# Cant convert string to NSDate

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert string to NSDate. I suppose that my dateFormat is ok, but i still receive nil.
My code:

```
        let dateStr = tweet.objectForKey("created_at") as! String
        print(dateStr)
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
        let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr)
        print(date)
```

Output:

```
Mon Apr 04 20:12:54 +0000 2016
nil
Mon Apr 04 14:17:09 +0000 2016
nil
Mon Apr 04 14:07:32 +0000 2016
nil
Sun Feb 21 12:37:23 +0000 2016
nil
```

Comment: Just tried your code with "Mon Apr 04 20:12:54 +0000 2016" for dateStr and it worked for me. Can you provide more code?

Comment: I've tried also in playground with this string date and everything was fine. I'm getting this date value from twitter JSON. Maybe it is the problem. I've posted all JSON here: http://pastebin.com/SW6UiYEk

Comment: I can also confirm this is working in Playground.

Comment: Try wrapping the date formatter in if let dateStr = tweet.objectForKey("created_at") as? String {....}

Comment: I've found the answer here. Thanks everybody who tried to help!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045222/nsdateformatter-not-working-for-twitter-date

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same code and it's working for me. Assuming, you are getting correct value for `dateStr` as it is shown in Output.

```
    let dateStr = "Mon Apr 04 20:12:54 +0000 201"
    print(dateStr)
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr)
    print(date!)
```

Output:

Mon Apr 04 20:12:54 +0000 2016

2016-04-04 20:12:54 +0000

See attached screenshot
[image]